# signature on pdf from SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, reporting-services

I am creating a quarterly report for several individuals.  Each is responsible for specific areas of the business.  I am generating a report that will be sent to the individuals via email.  The report will need to be reviewed and either signed and accepted or rejected.  I would like to send the report generated with an rdl from visual studio and stored in SharePoint.  Ideally, I would like to have a fillable PDF form that the user adds their name and date and then returns to me.
If there is a way to capture the name and date as an update to the database I would be in heaven.  I am willing to crawl before I walk though.
I am using SQL Server 2012, SharePoint Foundation 2010 and Visual Studio 2010.